# Understanding 'GET' routes in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my routes file I have specified:

```
resources :cards do
end
```

Apart from the basic CRUD routes I have another route which is as follows:

```
get '/cards/get_schema' => 'cards#get_schema'
```

When I hit this endpoint, I'm actually taken to `cards#show`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

One route generated by `resources :cards` is `get '/cards/:id'`. Can you see the issue? `get_schema` is recognized as id. Try this one

```
resources :cards do
  get 'get_schema', on: :collection
end
```

Or just put that route on top

```
get '/cards/get_schema' => 'cards#get_schema'
resources :cards
```

Answer (score 1):

> It depends on the order of routes defined.

**Order 1**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :cards do
  end

  get '/cards/get_schema' => 'cards#get_schema'
end
```

Running routes

```
rake routes
```

**Output**

```
~/D/p/p/s/console_test> rake routes
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
           cards GET    /cards(.:format)            cards#index
                 POST   /cards(.:format)            cards#create
        new_card GET    /cards/new(.:format)        cards#new
       edit_card GET    /cards/:id/edit(.:format)   cards#edit
            card GET    /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#show #<======== 
                 PATCH  /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#update
                 PUT    /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#update
                 DELETE /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#destroy
cards_get_schema GET    /cards/get_schema(.:format) cards#get_schema #<========
```

Since show expects `cards/:id` and is above `/cards/get_schema` it gets routed to `cards#show`

**Order 2**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get '/cards/get_schema' => 'cards#get_schema'

  resources :cards do
  end

end
```

Running routes

```
rake routes
```

**Output**

```
  ~/D/p/p/s/console_test> rake routes
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
cards_get_schema GET    /cards/get_schema(.:format) cards#get_schema #<========
           cards GET    /cards(.:format)            cards#index
                 POST   /cards(.:format)            cards#create
        new_card GET    /cards/new(.:format)        cards#new
       edit_card GET    /cards/:id/edit(.:format)   cards#edit
            card GET    /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#show #<========
                 PATCH  /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#update
                 PUT    /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#update
                 DELETE /cards/:id(.:format)        cards#destroy
```

In this scenario `/cards/get_schema` will be top level and won't conflict with `cards#show`

Answer (score 1):

Rails is treating `get_schema` as the id of a card. The solution is to reorder the route declarations, like so:

```
get '/cards/get_schema' => 'cards#get_schema'

resources :cards do
end
```

This way the `get_schema` route will be matched before the `show` route.